# Записывать звук с микрофона в фоне Java(Android)

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать запись звука с микрофона (маленькие фрагменты ~1с) и конвертировать его в string. также нужно сделать это в фоне и зациклить чтобы получился поток звука из микрофона, конвертированый в текст(Base64).

---

Буду рад любым ответам, но желательно код

Comment: Ваш бы вопрос закрыть, но давайте начнём отсюда: https://goo-gl.su/dx2027vs. Нужно делать самому, а если не получается, тогда приходить сюда.

Comment: Если бы получалось я бы сюда не приходил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос состоит из нескольких частей:

1. Запись аудио из микрофона. В стандарте это делается через `MediaRecorder`, штука строго асинхронная, так что если вы не понимаете что такое асинхронность и event-driven programming - лучше откажитесь. [Руководство здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder)
2. Теперь надо вынести запись аудио в фон. Это делается через `Service`, сервисы тоже весь в себе. [Руководство к сервисам здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)
3. Далее конвертация аудио в текст. Здесь то как раз все просто. Есть масса облачных сервисов, засовываете к ним аудио поток и получаете обратно текст. Естественно все платно (или почти все).

Если думаете самостоятельно реализовать аудио в текст - это путь героя.

Comment: Мне не надо разпознавать текст из аудио. Мне нужно конвертировать записаный файл в строку для дальнейшей передачи файла(в виде строки).

Comment: @Maks, просто переводите в аудиопоток в байты и сохраняйте в файл. Если же, нужна именно строка, тогда конвертируете байты аудипотока, например, в base64

Comment: @Maks тогда все совсем просто. `MediaRecorder` умеет записывать в файл аудио поток. Далее берете файл, конвертируете его в base64 и все